How to autoplay an audio even when the page is not active
Have a list, in which the names of the songs I want to play are placed in an order...when I have to play the next one, my function gets the currently playing song's index, and plays the next one in the list.
toPlay = autoPlayOrder[(autoPlayOrder.indexOf(playing)) + 1]
play(toPlay)

here,

autoPlayOrder is the list which has the songs to play
playing is the song which is currently playing
play() is a function I have that just plays the song

Now the system works as expected when the page is loaded but when im on another webpage, then when the song stops the next one isn't autoplayed...after some testing I concluded that this is due to the reason that javascript isnt allowed to run when the page is not active.
During my testing, I had the page active and the code did what it was supposed to...then I did the same thing but this time i switched the tab and so the next audio didnt autoplay as it was supposed to and as it had previously done..plus as soon as i switched back to the tab it started playing
Just another side note, I was almost facing the same issue when i tried to make a loop song feature, but managed to work around that by using the inbuilt loop feature in an audio element in html.

"im guessing this is due to the reason that javascript isnt allowed to run when the page is not active" - don't guess, test: https://jsfiddle.net/5ngz7b6r/ - or ask on SO: can javascript run when tab not in focus Keeping script running when tab is not the focus etc

well i did my research before posting this question and I realised that setInterval() and setTimeout() functions run in the background...most of the similar questions on stackoverflow were about making a timer that isnt running in the background/when the tab not active....so im pretty sure its not running the background and thats the reason....it works smoothly when the page is active and also immediately runs when i switch back to the tab after the time it was supposed to play but didn't

I found the solution, the <audio> tag in HTML has an inbuilt onended attribute in which we can pass our own function. So just create a function and pass that in the onended attribute and it will work even if the webpage is not active/loaded
